# PhoneGap and WhatsApp

Tags: android, html, cordova, whatsapp

I hope you'll can help me to find an issue to my problem.

I'm developping an application who should use WhatsApp. This application is using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript. I am using this link to send an message with WhatsApp :

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Test 1">
```

This link work perfectly when you use directly a browser but when I use PhoneGap I have a error like this :

> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I have tested some issues but doesn't work. I have also checked the Documentation but nothing...

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the solution to my problem (thanks to @jcesarmobile):

```
<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit for newer cordova versions:

Use `<allow-intent href="whatsapp:*" />`

Old answer:

Add this line to your config.xml

```
<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Or use the social sharing plugin

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via WhatsApp (with errcallback)</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working :) . I just use this line : `<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />`

Comment: i used <access..... code but its not working for me is there anything else i can check out.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla, try with `<allow-intent href="whatsapp:*" />`

Comment: and what's the error? you didn't mention anything about an error. You should probably create your own question and provide more information

Answer (score 2):

First and more important, add this line to your config.xml

```
<allow-intent href="whatsapp:*" />
```

after use the code:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = 'whatsapp://send?text=hello world';
```

this worked for phonegap IOS

```
window.open("'whatsapp://send?text=hello world'", "_system");
```

for android.